# How do I speed up the perception of time?

Tags: super-powers

In Jojo's Bizzare Adventure, a specific character get the ability to allow him to accelerate the time of the world and himself to the point that he looks as though he is moving faster than a bullet (or basically the Flash). However, what I want to do is to make someone perceive time so slowly that everything around them is moving at superspeed (basically a debuff to grant the illusion of superspeed to everyone else or makes 10 minutes feel like a second). As for powers, my character has the ability to control all cells within any given body so long as the cells are in physical contact with each other. However, he can also infect people with those same cells to control/manipulate their bodies via chemical signals/pheromones. However, I don't have the full science down to how he can make people perceive time quickly, but I am sure that something can.

Comment: "Controlling all cells" in someone's body isn't science, it's magic.  With magic on your side, just say he can control someone's temporal perception, problem solved.

Comment: (It's worth noting that there is no _biological_ way to do this, because we have a host of rough temporal indicators that have to continue operating or the person perceiving the flow of time will die.  Heartbeat and respiration cannot slow sufficiently to make ten minutes feel like a second.)

Comment: When I get up in the morning it certainly feels like I can zone out for a second and have 10 minutes pass...

Comment: I was looking more toward the area where cells could be rearranged in such a way that it could be possible. The whole premise behind this particular character is that he is the only non-magical being in a magical world, where life can't exist without magic (basically he was isekaied).

Comment: If he's non-magical, he cannot control/rearrange individual cells.  If you want to call it "science", then that's fine, but it's still magic and doesn't obey any actual scientific rules.

Comment: There is a state of stoned where the world feels like a slide show. How would what you have in mind differ from having the person essentially unconscious for a significant percentage of the time?

Comment: As a further addendum, if the goal is to make the afflicted individual think that the hero or someone else has superspeed, it's not going to work.  Assuming that [saccades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccade) don't continue operating at normal speeds and render any vision a blur, all the usual signals of time's arrow (items moving in the wind, the perceived acceleration of gravity) would be increased to the same amount.

Comment: This rearranged individual cells ability is just some sci-fi bs. Basically, scientists from the future want to cure cancer and instead make him, a sentient mass of cells that can rearrange into any form the user wished. So perfect disguises, hidden bone blade weapons, and crossbow made of muscle fibers, the list goes on.

Comment: Not to tell future oncologists how to do their jobs, but that sounds more like a method to create horrifying new cancers than to cure them.

Comment: @Cadence it's more like they originally wanted to make cells to be able to naturally rewrite their DNA. One thing led to another and they were like fuck it let's make a sentient bioweapon for assassinations.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to somehow delay the speed at which brain signals travel and are processed, that would cause the person to think slower and thereby percieve everything else as faster. Slowing down sensory inputs and motor-control outputs would probably fall under the same process, perhaps you could say that your superhuman causes the cells making up nerves to become "sluggish" or "unmotivated".

It should be noted that if this character is evil, they could pretty easily kill any person if they control the cells of the heart to not beat, or if they're a hero, it might be a struggle for them to slow down the nerves enough for a combat advantage but not so much that the opponent dies of... hypoxia, I think, or whatever category "signals to breathe not reaching your lungs for ~10 minutes" would fall under.

Comment: To answer your question, this person is not evil but more of an anti-hero or someone who follows his own passion/feelings. If he wants someone dead, he will do it in the most humiliating or extravagant way possible. This ability is more for show rather than an actual battle. He wants to manipulate his opponent and an enormous crowd of people so that he is moving at fast than light speed without the use of magic. He was also a hero in another country so if he uses his traditional abilities they would find out it is him (he is a wanted criminal in the country the tournament is taking place).

Comment: @GuyRansom If the character is trying to do this to a crowd rather than only one person, and you're set on the biological aspect of doing this by controlling the cells of targets' bodies, then the difficulty for them increases exponentially. It might be easier, both for narrative justification and for the secrecy of your character's true identity, to employ something like the methods talked about [in this post about the reverse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/175056/living-at-mach-50), "Living At Mach 50"

Comment: How far is he going, anyway? There should be plenty of room to be inconceivably, imperceptibly fast without getting anywhere near *c*. For instance if they're fighting in a space that's 30m across, light could travel from one end to the other *ten million times per second*. Even at a casual one ten-thousandth of that speed, he could cross that space in about a millisecond, so fast that observers wouldn't even perceive him as moving.